# SubmissionError with sync submit handler in redux-form

Tags: redux, redux-form

On redux-form, I can propagate a general form error from an async submit handler by throwing a `SubmissionError` just like described [here](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.5/examples/submitValidation/). However, this doesn't seem to work when my submit handler doesn't return a promise. Is there way to achieve the same error propagating behavior of async submit handler with sync submit handler?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  However, you could return an immediate Promise.resolve() from your handler.